# Typeclasses vs. functions?

Tags: haskell, typeclass

I am currently experimenting with typeclasses & as an exercise, the ability to log in a variety of contexts *(i.e. print to the console in the context of IO)*. I started off by implementing my **Logger** as a typeclass made up of various functions for logging with the idea in mind that I could define an instance for the IO monad but leave room for additional implementation in the context of other monads.

The end result is :

```
-- |Class / wrapper for convenient use within another monad.
class Logger m where
    -- |Logs an error message /(prefixed with the '__[ERROR]__' tag)/
    logError    :: String -> m ()
 
    -- |Logs a warning message /(prefixed with the '__[WARNING]__' tag)/
    logWarning  :: String -> m ()

    -- |Logs a success message /(prefixed with the '__[SUCCESS]__' tag)/
    logSuccess  :: String -> m ()

    -- |Logs an informative message /(prefixed with the '__[INFO]__' tag)/
    logInfo     :: String -> m ()

    -- |Logs a regular message /(i.e with no prefix)/
    logMsg      :: String -> m ()

-- |Instance of logger in the IO monad
instance Logger IO where
    logError    = printError
    logWarning  = printWarning
    logSuccess  = printSuccess
    logInfo     = printInfo
    logMsg      = printMsg

-- |Instance of logger for a state
instance (MonadIO m) => Logger (StateT s m) where
    logError    = liftIO . printError
    logWarning  = liftIO . printWarning
    logSuccess  = liftIO . printSuccess
    logInfo     = liftIO . printInfo
    logMsg      = liftIO . printMsg
```

This seemed like a good idea at the time *(and coming from an OOP background I am drawn to making everything into 'classes' when I probably shouldn't)*

I have come to realise I could have just as easily defined my logging functions directly with type contraints and call it a day, e.g. :

```
logError :: (MonadIO m) => String -> m ()
logError = liftIO . printError
```

And so on for the other functions and I would have something that can be called in any IO-based monad...

---

Obviously, both solutions have got their benefits and their trade-offs.

Could my use-case of a typeclass for **Logger** be considered *"abuse"* or do I have the right idea in implementing it that way *(my understanding is that type classes allow for ad hoc polymorphism which is what I had in mind)*.

One limitation I have read about & which I am still trying to fully conceptualise is the fact there can only be one instance of a typeclass for any given type, so in my case, I have already defined an instance for **StateT** which live in the **IO** monad, meaning I lose the ability to override for subsquent states with the same signature. I am aware of this caveat but I am having a hard time thinking of a situation where this would become a concrete problem.

On the flip side, the simple function-based approach is just as elegant to use although it does prevent overriding the behaviour without defining a brand new function to be used in a different context.

**Should typeclasses only be used/written as a last resort when functions can just as easily do the job?**

I would appreciate some insight and feedback on the two approaches.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: One question per post please.

Comment: I have updated my post to only feature one question, thanks.

Comment: Haskell is easy to refactor. So go with the simple solution first.

Comment: I appreciate that Haskell is so easy to refactor but my question was more geared towards the thought process & intuition that comes into play when deciding to write a typeclass vs. regular functions.

Comment: That's exactly the though process: you start with the minimal solution that works, and then, as you realize the need, you refactor.

Comment: I think your `StateT` instance should have a different constraint: `instance Logger m => Logger (StateT s m) where logError = lift . logError`, etc.

Comment: Since you come from an object-oriented background and ask about logging, you may find my article series on [Repeatable execution](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2020/03/23/repeatable-execution) useful. The three-part series includes a full Haskell example, including all source code on GitHub.

Comment: Thanks, I shall definitely have a read.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Absolutely reuse typeclasses that already do the thing you care about -- in this case, `MonadIO`.

That said, I think logging is an especially interesting application. For example, consider `AccumT [String] IO`. Should the log lift an `IO` operation, or `add`? It's not super clear that one is clearly correct and the other clearly incorrect. For that reason, you might even consider going from the typeclass route -- which can only have one implementation per type -- to the ADT route:

```
-- incidentally, you should use this in your class, too
data Level = Error | Warning | Success | Info | Msg
    deriving (Eq, Ord, Read, Show, Bounded, Enum)

newtype Logger m = Logger { log :: Level -> String -> m () }
```

Then you could have separate implementations for `AccumT`:

```
makeLoggingMessage :: Level -> String -> String
makeLoggingMessage lev msg = show lev ++ ": " ++ msg -- or whatever

viaIO :: MonadIO m => Logger m
viaIO = Logger $ \lev msg -> liftIO . putStrLn $ makeLoggingMessage lev msg

viaAccum :: Monad m => Logger (AccumT [String] m)
viaAccum = Logger $ \lev msg -> add [makeLoggingMessage lev msg]
```

There might be other variants, too; maybe one that adds a timestamp and one that doesn't, for example.

By the way, this data type suggestion is not merely academic. The lumberjack library's [LogAction](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lumberjack-1.0.0.0/docs/Lumberjack.html#t:LogAction) data type<sup>1</sup> is almost exactly this, has a whole library built around it, and is used by professional Haskell programmers.

Choosing between the three options -- existing typeclass, new typeclass, or data type -- is something that you'll slowly gain experience at doing. As a rule of thumb, probably the most reliable advice I can give newcomers on this topic is: don't create a new typeclass. ^_^

<sup>1</sup>Some folks may also recognize this from the [co-log](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/co-log) library, which I'm told was a heavy inspiration in the design of lumberjack.

Comment: I had not considered the possibility to use newtype as you suggested, that is definitely an avenue I want to investigate. It looks more verbose in that you have to have differently named implementations but it does look far more powerful & extensible also. Alongside your answer and the previous comments I feel like this answers the question quite well as well as providing enough avenues that the benefits of the respective alternatives become clear.